# How to update Image being used in docker-compose.yml after it has moved to a new docker hub repo?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have recently gotten familiar with Docker but still somewhat new to docker-compose. I have a server running an application and a database each in their own containers. In the application's directory (/opt/my-app) there is a docker-compose.yml file that references a specific image to run for the application. Our application now lives in a different repo.

My question is, If I want to update to the new app (that resides in a different repo) do I manually pull the image, alter the docker-compose.yml file to reference and then run docker-compose start/up?

With just docker, I would run *docker stop containerName*

Then I would pull the new image, and *run docker run -d -p 8080:80 newImageName*

I'm just not certain of how this should be done with docker-compose.

Comment: Just edit `docker-compose.yml` and re-run `docker-compose up`.  It will figure out what has and hasn’t changed and needs to be recreated.

Comment: Thanks David - Should I stop the currently running application container first, or does it matter?

Comment: It will do it on its own.